# How do I get all values from a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have a column(missing col) that gets all the missing numbers from my id column. So from the entire range of cells most are empty, I want to make another column of just the values that are not empty - mainly cause there are thousands or rows and I need to see those numbers at the top. I have not seen two  missing in a row, but that would make a comma separated id cell - i.e. `PW140000024,PW140000025` - which may need to dealt with at some point.

Function that makes the missing col:

```
=IF(MID(E2,3,99)-MID(E1,3,99)>2,"PW"&MID(E1,3,99)+1&",PW"&MID(E2,3,99)-1,IF(MID(E2,3,99)-MID(E1,3,99)>1,"PW"&MID(E1,3,99)+1,""))
```

Example:

```
id column   | missing col             | missing without empty rows
PW140000023 |                         | PW140000024
PW140000025 | PW140000024             | PW140000027
PW140000026 | PW140000027             | PW140000029
PW140000028 | PW140000029,PW140000030 | PW140000030
PW140000031 |                         |
PW140000032 |                         |
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is it not possible just to order by missing col ?

Comment: @pnuts, well will not account for the comma separated part.

Comment: @Xion, No, please read updated post.

Comment: @pnuts, I just ran a larger file and found plenty of them, so it will be a must. I am not very great a complex excel stuff.

Comment: How about a loop of cells in that columns used range and if it contains a `,` then `Left` and `Right` the string and send to a new cell that increments with each iteration and between `Left` and `Right` otherwise just send the text to new cell - just don't know how to write that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this with the header row in row 1 and your data starting in row 2, the id columns is Column E and you want the "Missing" column to be column F:

[image: tigeravatar example]

In cell F2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IFERROR("PW"&INDEX(SUBSTITUTE($E$2,"PW","")+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDEX(--(SUBSTITUTE($E$2:$E$7,"PW","")),))-SUBSTITUTE($E$2,"PW","")+1))-1,
    MATCH(1,
        INDEX(
            (COUNTIF(F$1:F1,"*"&INDEX(SUBSTITUTE($E$2,"PW","")+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDEX(--(SUBSTITUTE($E$2:$E$7,"PW","")),))-SUBSTITUTE($E$2,"PW","")+1))-1,))=0)
             *
            (COUNTIF($E$2:$E$7,"*"&INDEX(SUBSTITUTE($E$2,"PW","")+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDEX(--(SUBSTITUTE($E$2:$E$7,"PW","")),))-SUBSTITUTE($E$2,"PW","")+1))-1,))=0)
        ,)
    ,0))
,"")
```

The formula will work great for small sets of data like this sample, but I can see how it would start slowing down Excel drastically for larger data sets.  Because of this complication, I would instead recommend creating a VBA subroutine to get the results for you.

Something like this should work:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const strIDcol As String = "E"  'Change to the actual column containing the id's
    Const strOPcol As String = "F"  'Change to the actual column you want to OutPut results to
    Const lStartRow As Long = 2     'Change to the row your data actually starts on (NOT the header row)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngIDs As Range
    Dim IDCell As Range
    Dim arrMissing() As String
    Dim MissingIndex As Long
    Dim IDMin As Long
    Dim IDMax As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'Assuming we're working with the active workbook and active worksheet
    Set rngIDs = Range(strIDcol & lStartRow, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, strIDcol).End(xlUp))

    IDMin = Val(Replace(rngIDs.Cells(1).Value, "PW", vbNullString))
    IDMax = Val(Replace(rngIDs.Cells(rngIDs.Cells.Count).Value, "PW", vbNullString))

    ReDim arrMissing(1 To IDMax - IDMin + 1 - rngIDs.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)

    For i = IDMin To IDMax
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(strIDcol), "*" & i) = 0 Then
            MissingIndex = MissingIndex + 1
            arrMissing(MissingIndex, 1) = "PW" & i
        End If
    Next i

    Range(strOPcol & lStartRow).Resize(MissingIndex).Value = arrMissing

End Sub
```

Comment: Out of range exception on VBA at `ReDim arrMissing` line. Error - The function will not enter as there are more levels of nestings than allowed for this file format - not word for word but close.

Comment: That's kinda weird, there aren't any levels of nesting in there... I tested it on my machine and it ran with no errors.

Comment: It highlighted the second MAX function after the message box.

Comment: error message box - when I hit the enter key on the cell containing the function

Comment: there are some duplicate ids - does that mess it up?

Comment: ah, yes, that would mess it up

Comment: sorry i didn't mention, this is a follow up question and i didn't think someone would try to improve the original function as an answer, but that would be awesome

Comment: So the function is the first thing I posted, the VBA solution which requires the VBA editor is the second thing. You can get into the VBA editor by pressing Alt+F11. In there go to Insert -> Module and paste the VBA code provided.  The formula you should just be able to copy paste into cell F2 and then copy down though it may slow down your Excel workbook significantly which is why I recommend the VBA solution instead.

Comment: To correct the issue of having duplicates, remove the `- rngIDs.Cells.Count` from the `ReDim arrMissing` line

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent result seems possible by creating a list of ids starting PW140000023 (say with `="PW"&140000022+row()` in Row1), matching these to `id column` (say with `=MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)` copying both down to suit, fixing those results as values and then filtering to delete numeric results for matches.